# Maplin Bluetooth Shield for Arduino - BAUD rate

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, shields, softwareserial, baud-rate

I am currently using a Bluetooth shield which i bought from maplin, see: http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/bluetooth-shield-for-arduino-n97dg.

I have got it to work perfectly on the default 38400 BAUD , but cannot get it working at any other baud rate. I am currently just modifying the base code ([here](http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=Bluetooth_Shield_for_Arduino)) given with the device where AT commands are used to configure the module.

I have tried setting the BAUD to say 115200 and then read back the devices BAUD rate using AT commands, and while it does return that it goes to 115200 it doesn't accept any commands after that.

Can any one offer help as to how I can reliably change to BAUD rate?

Comment: Have you changed the baud rate OF your serial monitor and IN you program.

Comment: Yes I have, the setup process involving sending the AT commands seems to go through successfully but when i run the test_bluetooth method, again with the BAUD changed there as well, the test fails. I have also tried connecting it with the Android device when the BAUD is changed and there is no communication, unlike when using 38400, which communicates perfectly